# Binding class property

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want bind one of my class property. I do it with `FileList.DataContext = fileManager;`
Below I put codebehind.

C#

```
 public class File : ListBoxItem
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { this.name = value; }
        }
        private string id;
        public string Id
        {
            get { return this.id; }
            set { this.id = value; }
        }
    }

public class FilesManager
    {
        public ObservableCollection<File> Files { get; set; }

        public FilesManager()
        {
            Files = new ObservableCollection<File>();
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<ListBox Name="FileList" Width="auto" Height="578" ItemsSource="{Binding Files, Mode=OneWay}" Tap="FileList_Tap" FontSize="36" Margin="0,14,0,15">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When app starts, data is assaigned, after that I get Application_UnhandledException, before binding was great. What I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE

```
// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
        private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }//here debugger stops.
```

Comment: What's the exception you're getting?

Comment: That's the wierdest. No exception, only code stope like breakpoint (but not mine) at end code that I add with my question update.

Comment: Is there not an exception on the `ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs`?

Comment: No, like I said it stops like I put breakpoint there but I didn't.

Comment: Where you create `Files` object? Is `FileList_Tap` handler are implemented? What `stringConv` converter is? Please localize a real problem and show a small amount of code as possible

Comment: I create `Files` object in FilesManager constructor. Yes FileList_Tap is implemented. Don't bother `stringConv` I remove it.

Comment: The debugger is breaking there because the project is (most likely) build in release mode). Build in debug. Also, do not extend ListBoxItem for your File class

Comment: Yea you have right! I change to debug mode and then it stops two line elier. What's more I delete extend, and it goes :) thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need inherite your class from ListBoxItem because you using ItemTemplate.

Use simple class and bind it to your list.

```
public class File 
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { this.name = value; }
        }
        private string id;
        public string Id
        {
            get { return this.id; }
            set { this.id = value; }
        }
    }
```